# Trigger animation issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

i have to animate a breadcrumb container from 0 top 68 px when window are scrolled more than 50 px. I use this :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50 ) {
        $(".breadcrumb_cont").one().animate({top:68});          
        } else {
        $(".breadcrumb_cont").one().animate({top:0});

    }
});
```

but it working only if i use the first step of code. when i add the else condition there are some problem... animate seem to conflict whit itself.
Where is the problem ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

checkout this fiddle

[just added a position to breadcrumb](http://jsfiddle.net/DkNGf/)

`.breadcrumb_cont {position:relative;}`